# Abstract Factory Pattern for Implementing AdNetworks on Multiple Platforms

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine

Here's the [link](https://github.com/usamaB/AdsSolution/tree/devel) to the github project.

I want to implement Abstract Factory instead of adding platform dependent compilation flags in just one file and make it ugly. Hence decoupled code. Moreover, I have to implement different AdNetworks on different platforms.

This is the interface

```
public interface IAds 
{
    void ShowVideoAd();
    void PreLoadVideoAd();
    bool IsAdAvailable();

}
```

And all the PlatformAdController(Android, IOS, Amazon, Windows) will implement this interface.

```
    public class AmazonAdsController : IAds
    {
// Code Goes here
    }
```

Then in *someFactoryClass* I'll do

```
public IAds GetObject()
{
    #if UNITY_Android
    if(platform == Amazon)
    return new AmazonAdsController
    else 
    return new AndroidAdsController
    #elif UNITY_IOS
    return new IOSAdsController
    #elif UNITY_WP10
    return new WindowsAdsController
}
```

This Method will be called from AdManager a Singleton MonoBehaviour. My current AdManager state is

```
namespace MS.Ads
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(KeyGenerator))]
    public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Fields & Properties
        [SerializeField]
        private KeysSource _keysSource;
        [SerializeField]
        [HideInInspector]
        private string _fileName;
        [SerializeField]
        [HideInInspector]
        private string _url;

        // Source from where to get keys
        public KeysSource Source
        {
            get { return _keysSource; }
            set { _keysSource = value; }
        }

        // Web URL from where to get AdKeys
        public string URL
        {
            get { return _url; }
            set { _url = value; }
        }

        // FileName from where to get Adkeys e.g adc.json
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _fileName; }
            set { _fileName = value; }
        }

        // To be replaced by a FactoryObject.
        private FyberController _fyberController;
        #endregion

        #region Message Methods
        void Start()
        {            
            GetComponent<KeyGenerator>().GenerateKeys(Source, URL, FileName);
            _fyberController = new FyberController();
            _fyberController.RequestVideoAd();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void ShowAd()
        {
            if (_fyberController.IsVideoAdAvailable)
                _fyberController.ShowVideoAd();
        }

        public bool IsVideoAdAvailable()
        {
            return _fyberController.IsVideoAdAvailable ? true : false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

What I would like to know

1. Is Factory Pattern the right choice here?
2. If yes, Should I go with an interface or an Abstract base class or a
   base class with virtual methods?

Comment: `if`ing in your `GetObject` doesn't look good, it makes the implementation violate the OCP principle - to add a new provider, you'd have to recompile the project. Instead, rely on an external parameter taken from anywhere, the config for example and match the value with a list of possible providers.

Comment: Yes you are right. What I could do is make different classes WinowsAdsFactory that would return the Product WindowsAdsController. 
`GetObject(RuntimePlatform platform, bool isAmazon = false)` the client will pass the `factoryProducer.GetObject(Application.platform)`
but I couldn't understand what you meant by **match the value with a list of possible providers**. Because even if I pass the parameters I have to check them especially in the case of **Amazon** which falls under **Android Platform**.

Comment: Why has this question verbatim appeared on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116239/abstract-factory-pattern-for-implementing-adnetworks-on-multiple-platforms) and [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119112/abstract-factory-pattern-for-implementing-adnetworks-on-multiple-platforms)? The username used there is different (SamBh)

Comment: @WiktorZychla maybe a Enum catering all the platforms and pass it to the GetObject fucntion. Which has a dictionary Action/Object 
`Dictionary< RuntimePlatform , Action>` or 
`Dictionary< RuntimePlatform , IAds>`

Comment: @usamakaleem: yes. If you also expose a method to add a possible new handler to this internal dictionary, you'll have an OCP-compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes you can use factory pattern here, and you are totally fine with that. Tomorrow if you have another Ads you can easily add it to the factory.

2- There are two ways to create factory patterns. **Abstract Factory pattern** delegates the responsibility of object instantiation to another object via composition and **Factory Method pattern** uses inheritance and relies on a subclass to handle the desired object instantiation. It depends on your needs.

In this case, you are using Factory Method pattern. It is more easier to use than Abstact Factory pattern.

Comment: Yes keeping this(can add another) need in my mind I opted for this pattern.
About point 2, while using Factory method should I make an AbstractBaseFactory and create separate concrete factories for different platforms and let them create their PlatformAdsController(product) or is it fine this way.

Comment: As I explained, if you have one factory it is Ok go with this now. But if you have separate factories go for the other design pattern which is **Abstract Factory pattern**.